# Radio buttons in the middle with two columns of text/options on each side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I'm trying to get radio buttons from [Flat UI](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/) aligned in the center. But it seems very difficult to achieve. The problem (as can be seen in the attached image is that I cannot bring the radios on the right to appear before the text on the second column.

Could anyone who's adept at CSS magic be able to tell me the right way to do it? I'm sorry I cannot provide a fiddle link (couldn't figure out how to port Flat-UI stuff inside there), but if you want to see my template, I'm willing to send you the link. Please let me know.

I'm open to using other UI/CSS tools if the looks is better than the regular radio button look from HTML. Thank you!

p.s. I tagged this with "twitter-bootstrap" because I believe Flat UI is built upon that.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in style sheet of flat-ui `:before` pseudo element is attached to radio button property. Results two icons for radio.

**SOLUTION :**

1. Go to style sheet of flat-ui
2. Search for `.fui-radio-unchecked:before` and `.fui-radio-checked:before`
3. Either remove them or keep both the properties in css comments `/**/`

That's it your problem will be solved.